# Must Invoke first design pattern

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I am looking for an elegant solution for my case. I tried to find a design pattern that specified and offers solution for this case but i failed to find one.

I have a base class that uses to store general object and later Invoke it.
I want the execution will be separated into two parts:

1. A must have part which will always take place (do1st()).
2. User defined code (do2nd()).

For example:

```
class InvokeBase
{
public:
    InvokeBase(void *ptr) : context_(ptr) {}
    virtual ~InvokeBase () {}
    void operator()() = 0; 
protected:
    void do1st() {//Mandatory code to execute for every InvokeBase type when calling operator()};
    void * context_;
};

class InvokeDerived : public InvokeBase
{
public: 
    InvokeDerived(void *ptr) : base(ptr){}
    virtual ~InvokeDerived();
    void do2nd() {//User defined code}
    void operator()()  
    {
        do1st();  // << How to force this execution?
        do2nd();
    } 
};

void main()
{
     InvokeBase *t = new InvokeDerived();
     t(); // << here i want the execution order will be do1st and then do2nd. 
}
```

The trick is that i want do1st will execute always, that i will not have to call it from InvokeDerived. I want to allow the user to inherit from InvokeBase with the guarantee that do1st will always be called when invoking the operator().

Comment: [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

Comment: `void* context` is a C solution. In C++, we have multiple better solutions. In this case, the solution would be to just remove `context` as it's unused. It's also unclear why `InvokeBase` would hold the context, as it appears far more logical to store context in `InvokeDerived`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the template method pattern: split a function with semi-flexible behavior accross the class hierarchy into multiple parts, and make virtual only the ones that change:

```
class InvokeBase
{
public:
    InvokeBase(void *ptr) : context_(ptr) {}
    virtual ~InvokeBase () {}
    void operator()() // this is non-virtual (this is the template method)
    {
        do1st();
        do2nd(); // this resolves to virtual call
    }

protected:
    void do1st() { /* fixed code here */ };
    virtual void do2nd() = 0; // variable part here
    void * context_;
};

class InvokeDerived : public InvokeBase
{
public: 
    InvokeDerived(void *ptr) : base(ptr){}
    virtual ~InvokeDerived() = default;

protected:
    void do2nd() override
    {
        // code speciffic to InvokeDerived here
    }
};
```